# Size of the Custom popup window using Interaction request

Tags: prism

I used a custom confirmation popup window, this the XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="150"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="6" Grid.Row="1">
            <Button x:Name="YesBtn" Width="100" Content="OK" Click="OnOk_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="NoBtn" Width="100" Content="No" Click="OnNo_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and this is the code behide:

```
public partial class CustomConfirmation : IInteractionRequestAware
{
    public CustomConfirmation()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public IConfirmation Confirmation
    {
        get { return this.DataContext as IConfirmation; }
        set { this.DataContext = value; }
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Confirmed { get; set; }
    public INotification Notification { get; set; }
    public Action FinishInteraction { get; set; }
    private void OnOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FinishInteraction != null)
        {
            Confirmation.Confirmed= true;
            FinishInteraction();
        }
    }

    private void OnNo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FinishInteraction != null)
        {
            Confirmation.Confirmed = false;
            FinishInteraction();
        }
    }
}
```

In view model class i have :

- two commands(DispalyLongTextCommand and DispalyShortTextCommand): one
  to display long message and the other to display a short message
- and i have InteractionRequest ConfirmationRequest
  object initialized in ctor to raise intercations.

if I display the long message first my custom window resize its content to the hole message, it is OK!
but if a want to display the short message, my window keeps the previous size!

note : even i set the window SizeToContent style to WidthAndHeight but it not working.

```html
<ei:Interaction.Triggers>
        <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding ConfirmationRequest, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True">
                <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="Window">
                        <Setter Property="SizeToContent" Value="WidthAndHeight"/>
                    </Style>
                </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowStyle>
                <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                    <local:CustomConfirmation/>
                </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction>
        </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
    </ei:Interaction.Triggers>
```

[image: size of the window depends on the content]

[image: Window keep the previous size]

can you guide me, 
thanks in advance

**SOLUTION:**
I fixed the problem by adding this code in the code behind of the custom popup window,  :

```
public CustomConfirmationView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += CustomPopupView_Loaded;
    }

    private void CustomPopupView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var parentWindow = this.Parent as Window;
        if (parentWindow != null)
        {
            parentWindow.Measure(parentWindow.DesiredSize);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The WindowContent property is reused each time you show a new popup.  So, what happens is that when you first show a popup, the CustomPopupView is visualized and the height is set based on the current content.  Now, when you close the popup, and change the content to a larger message and then show it again, the CustomPopupView.Height has already been set by the previous action and isn't updated in time for the new Window to get the correct height.  So you must now resize the Window to match the new size of the CustomPopupView height.  So just add a little code to handle this in your code-behind like this:

```
    public CustomPopupView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += CustomPopupView_Loaded;
    }

    private void CustomPopupView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var parentWindow = this.Parent as Window;
        if (parentWindow != null)
            parentWindow.MinHeight = _txt.ActualHeight + 75;
    }
```

Note:  '_txt' is the name of the TextBlock with the Content binding.

Comment: what you mean? you mean that I change the grid by a StackPanel?, I tried what you suggested but still not working,  Can you explain more, thank you Brian for your time.

Comment: I took the time to test this out personally and found the issue.  It is related to how the WPF Window manages it's layout.  I edited my answer to provide a fix.

Comment: thanks Brian for your answer and your time, I tried everything i know about height, width, layouts in xaml, but your fix does not resolve the problem.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you.  It worked for me.  The only other solution would be to design your popup so that it looks good no matter what size content you put in there, or use two different popups.

Comment: @toumir seems like you did use a similar approach after all

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with the default confirmation window that ships with Prism. The MinWidth and MinHeight are set in the XAML to 300 and 150, respectively. So, the window width/weight will never get any smaller no matter what the window content is. Overriding the window style will not be enough to do what you need.

You could download the Prism code and remove that limitation if you are comfortable enough with that. The source path to the file you would want to start with is below.

\Source\Wpf\Prism.Wpf\Interactivity\DefaultPopupWindows\DefaultConfirmationWindow.xaml

Either that, or ask the Prism team to see if they can make this more flexible, which is probably a better suggestion. You can post this as an issue on their GitHub page. https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues